# JIRA API: Get epic for issue

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way in which I could get the epic for an issue ?

The api returns a lot of information about an issue, but the epic is not included.

I'm using the JIRA REST API (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs).

Comment: Have you read [API for finding Epic Links](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/149394/api-for-finding-epic-links)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I wanted to extract the epic name for an `issue` and this stumped me for a few days.
The key was to realise that an `epic` is *just a parent issue*, and the **epic name** is the `summary` field of the parent `issue`.

So:

**Step 1**

Find the custom field of where the epic is stored by using the `editmeta` query:

https://[your-jira-hostname]/jira/rest/api/2/issue/[issue-number]/editmeta

This will yield something like below which reveals the custom field Id we need

```
{
  "fields": {
    <SNIP>
    "customfield_12360": {
      "required": false,
      "schema": {
        "type": "any",
        "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-link",
        "customId": 12360
      },
      "name": "Epic Link",
      "operations": [
        "set"
      ]
    }
    <SNIP>
  }
}
```

**Step 2**

Query your issue, pulling out the custom field value

https://[your-jira-hostname]/jira/rest/api/2/issue/[issue-number]?fields=customfield_12360,summary

if our issue is `JIRA-34` say, this will yield something like

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "39080",
  "key": "JIRA-34",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "Write heavily upvoted answers for stack overflow",
    "customfield_12360": "JIRA-33"
  }
}
```

**Step 3**

Now we know the issue number of our epic is `JIRA-33`, so now query the epic...

https://[your-jira-hostname]/jira/rest/api/2/issue/JIRA-33?fields=summary

```
{
      "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
      "id": "39080",
      "key": "JIRA-33",
      "fields": {
        "summary": "Improve StackOverflow reptuation"
      }
    }
```

The name of the epic for `JIRA-34` is "Improve StackOverflow reptuation"

Done.

Comment: Nice! I am not sure if this was supported in the API at the time. Good find!

Comment: Instead of *Step 1*, you can find out the epic link custom field by querying the custom fields API directly, without needing an issue key/id: `/rest/api/3/field/search?type=custom&query=Epic%20Link`. This is useful if you need to pull out epic links from a call to the issue search API for example. API docs are here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-field-search-get

Comment: @MikeRippon I think that suggestion is good enough as a separate answer (especially as this answer uses the v2 of the API and might not have that ability). Care to make one? I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

To get the epic key for an issue:

Send a request to: /issue/ISSUE-NUMBER

And look at the response body:

```
{
    ...,
    fields: {
        ...,
        customfield_11300: ... <- here, the epic should be listed. The number can be different
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I wonder if you could point any knowledge as to *why* this is the case, or where it would be documented what the exact customField is (and how to find out if it would be different).

Comment: I really don't know, the documentation was not so good at the time. Maybe try and look into Greenhopper's API.

Comment: customFields will likely change on a per-jira-instance basis. Meaning, the custom field your epic link shows up in for you will be different from mine. Mine is `customfield_10101`, for example. So this is not a reliable way of retrieving the epic link.

Answer (score 0):

@fiat have the very clear steps to find the custom field and epic mapping. In my scenario, the whole jira instance is using the same custom field as epic. So I won't need to repeat those steps to map for each project.
Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-fields/ , you can make a API call to `/rest/api/3/field`, then you can get data like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "customfield_10014",
    "key": "customfield_10014",
    "name": "Epic Link",
    "untranslatedName": "Epic Link",
    "custom": true,
    "orderable": true,
    "navigable": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "clauseNames": [
      "cf[10014]",
      "Epic Link"
    ],
    "schema": {
      "type": "any",
      "custom": "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-link",
      "customId": 10014
    }
  },
]
```

Then look back to your issue json data:

```yaml
issue:
  fields:
    ....
    customfield_10014: OT-5
    ....
```

The `OT-5` is the Epic's key.